# Is it possible to get and use a JavaSparkContext from within a task?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I've come across a situation where I'd like to do a "lookup" within a Spark and/or Spark Streaming pipeline (in Java).  The lookup is somewhat complex, but fortunately, I have some existing Spark pipelines (potentially DataFrames) that I could reuse.

For every incoming record, I'd like to *potentially* launch a spark job from the task to get the necessary information to decorate it with.

Considering the performance implications, would this *ever* be a good idea?

Not considering the performance implications, is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is it possible to get and use a JavaSparkContext from within a task?*

No. The spark context is only valid on the driver and Spark will prevent serialization of it. Therefore it's not possible to use the Spark context from within a task.

> *For every incoming record, I'd like to potentially launch a spark job
>   from the task to get the necessary information to decorate it with.
>   Considering the performance implications, would this ever be a good
>   idea?*

Without more details, my umbrella answer would be: *Probably not a good idea*.

> *Not considering the performance implications, is this even possible?*

Yes, probably by bringing the base collection to the driver (`collect`) and iterating over it. If that collection doesn't fit in memory of the driver, please previous point.

If we need to process every record, consider performing some form of `join` with the 'decorating' dataset - that will be only 1 large job instead of tons of small ones.